# jQuery not working with XMLHttpRequest object

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an **index.php** page which loads **info.php** through **AJAX**. The *info.php* content is loaded like this:

```
<script>
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "info.php", true);
  xhttp.send();
}

(function() {
   loadDoc()
})();
setInterval ( "loadDoc()", 5000 );
</script>
```

The *info.php* file has the following code to do a count up/down from/to a specific number.

```
<div class="timer count-title count-number" data-from="2000" data-to="300" data-speed="1500"></div>

<script src='includes/jquery-3.2.1.min.js'></script>
<script  src="includes/counter.js"></script>
```

When I visit *info.php* directly the counter works perfectly fine. However, if I visit *index.php*, the counter is not even showing. I had the same issue with other jQuery scripts. Even if *index.php* includes jQuery and the other scripts it still doesn't work. I do want the number to go through the AJAX call since it keeps updating.

Is there a simple solution?

Comment: This is not a jQuery script. It is VanillaJS

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. Neither jQuery or vanilla JS work if they are loaded in through the AJAX call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it by JQuery like as follow...

```
function loadDoc(){
            console.log( "call done" );
            $( "#data" ).load( "info.php", function() {
              console.log( "Load done." );
            });

        };
        $(function(){loadDoc();});
        setInterval (loadDoc, 5000 );
```

I think their problem with your function statement checks this for the following script...

```
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "info.php", true);
  xhttp.send();
}

$(function(){loadDoc();});
setInterval (loadDoc, 5000 );
```